# uml Is it possible for two classes to have relations more than 2?

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I make these two calsses and try to express it to UML Class diagram

```
publc Class A
{
    public A(){}     
    public void Funct1()
    {
        B b = new B(this);
    }
}

public Class B
{
    A m_A = null;
    public B(A a)
    {
        m_A = a
    }
}
```

I think class "A" have "Dependency" to B becuase A don't maintain reference to B
And I think class "B" have "one directional Association to A" because class B maintain reference to A.

So, I draw class diagram as follow.

```
        dependency
        -------->
     [A]        [B]
           <-
 one directioinal association
```

But, this diagram looks somewhat wrong even to me.
So, I want to know How to express this relation between these classes to class diagram.

Answer (score 2):

No, that seems perfectly valid to me for the reasons you mentioned yourself.

The only thing is that is "somewhat wrong" is the fact that you have a bi-directional dependency between A and B, making the two classes tightly coupled. You should avoid tight coupling whenever possible, but sometimes you don't have much other options.

Answer (score 0):

there is just association needed to define in UML for your example. But, it is not possible to determine what multiplicity is at the B side, multiplicity at A side is 0..1 if there is possible to set null to m_A.
No dependency is necessary to draw in UML in your example. Dependency does not have runt time impact. It is defined between model element definition. 
Read UML Superstructure to get precise information about dependency relationship.